# AWS MQTT payload dynamo action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, mqtt, aws-iot

I have a payload from MQTT coming in as

```
{id: 'id', v: {...}}
```

I wish for the payloads to append themselves to a list inside a dynamo table.

However, I am unable to perform the required operation in message column. Instead of appending, they overwrite the list. Please help what I am missing here.

My query selector is

```
SELECT VALUE [{"t": parse_time("yyyyMMddHHmm", timestamp(),"Asia/Singapore"), "v": v}] FROM 'DATA'
```

My action can select proper primary keys, but fails to append to a list column for the said primary key.
Regards.

Comment: How are you appending data on dynamo? Are you using a lambda function for this operation?

Comment: No, using a dynamo action on my table. The doc says I can use a field called OPERATION to be INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE, but I cannot understand where do I do this in the dynamo action ?
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/dynamodb-rule.html)

Comment: This dynamoDB actions are very simple, I might be wrong because I haven't played much with it but as far I know you can only do simple operations with it. In your scenario, it would be best to send your payload first to a lambda function and then appending the value to the list inside your record on a dynamodb table, like this:

Key={
        'hash_key': hash_key,
        'range_key': range_key
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET some_attr = list_append(some_attr, :i)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':i': [some_value],
    },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"

Comment: Yeah thats what I ended up doing... However, I am sure the above can be performed with a dynamo action.